# Finding the differences between rows associated by value in Pandas

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I need some help figuring out how to add a value from one column to other columns from within the same dataframe.

For example I have df with randomly generated data:

```
df = pd.DataFrame({'user_id': [123, 123, 246, 246, 135, 135],
                   'period': [1, 2, 1, 2, 1, 2],
                   'value1': [0, 5, 3, 1, 6, 3],
                   'value2': [5, 5, 2, 5, 4, 7],
                   'value3': [10, 15, 35, 25, 60, 50]})


   | user_id |period| value1 | value2 | value3 |
   |---------|------|--------|--------|--------|
0  |  123    |   1  |   0    |   5    |   10   |
1  |  123    |   2  |   5    |   5    |   15   |
2  |  246    |   1  |   3    |   2    |   35   |
3  |  246    |   2  |   1    |   5    |   25   |
4  |  135    |   1  |   6    |   4    |   60   |
5  |  135    |   2  |   3    |   7    |   50   |
```

So in the above df, I would take the value from the column 'value3', and add it to the values in 'value1' and 'value2', while retaining the other columns.

```
df2

   | user_id |period| value1 | value2 | value3 |
   |---------|------|--------|--------|--------|
0  |  123    |   1  |   10   |   15   |   10   |
1  |  123    |   2  |   20   |   20   |   15   |
2  |  246    |   1  |   38   |   37   |   35   |
3  |  246    |   2  |   26   |   30   |   25   |
4  |  135    |   1  |   66   |   64   |   60   |
5  |  135    |   2  |   53   |   57   |   50   |
```

I tried hardcoding the actual addition, but was met with error codes.

I know I'm probably missing something simple. Any advice?

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Specify `axis=0` when you add a Series to a DataFrame.

```
cols = ['value1', 'value2']
df[cols] = df[cols].add(df['value3'], axis=0)

   user_id  period  value1  value2  value3
0      123       1      10      15      10
1      123       2      20      20      15
2      246       1      38      37      35
3      246       2      26      30      25
4      135       1      66      64      60
5      135       2      53      57      50
```

Comment: This works. I knew it was something simple. Much appreciated.

Answer (score 1):

We can do `numpy` spread

```
df.update(df[['value1','value2']]+df.value3.values[:,None])
df
   user_id  period  value1  value2  value3
0      123       1      10      15      10
1      123       2      20      20      15
2      246       1      38      37      35
3      246       2      26      30      25
4      135       1      66      64      60
5      135       2      53      57      50
```

Comment: Great answer. Definitely wouldn't have thought of it this way. Thank you!